# Sizing a message box in SWT (Eclipse Platform API)

Tags: java, swt

I have to display a message box on some action, I am able to do that but the message dialog box appears smaller in size.Is there any way to increase the size of the message box in java?

here is my code:

```
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable () {
 @Override
 public void run() {
// Get active window page
   IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
  IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
  Shell parent  = window.getShell();
  MessageBox dialog = 
  new MessageBox(shell,SWT.RESIZE|SWT.ICON_INFORMATION|SWT.OK);

  dialog.setText("Project info");
  dialog.setMessage("Project info Text will come here");
  int returnCode = dialog.open(); 
  System.out.println("returnCode "+ returnCode);
  }     
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own dialog box. Take a look at the examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/ShellDialogExample.htm). I've copied the relevant code, in case that link stops working:

```
public class DialogExample extends Dialog {

    public DialogExample(Shell parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    public String open() {
        Shell parent = getParent();
        Shell dialog = new Shell(parent, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM
            | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setSize(100, 100);
        dialog.setText("Java Source and Support");
        dialog.open();
        Display display = parent.getDisplay();
        while (!dialog.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        return "After Dialog";
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        new DialogExample(new Shell());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know SWT uses the OS system message box so this means you can only change the title/text and icon type.

But you could use JFace which is an extension to SWT and try to use org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog API.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version: You don't hardcode your dialog size, rather make it variable on the user's screen size.

I've added my personal helper methods below, and demonstrated their usage.

This would be far more flexible than an OS `MessageBox`, but you're gonna have to add icons manually (oooooor I think you can even override `MessageDialog` instead of `Dialog` - your call)

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Monitor;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

/**
 * 
 * @author stackoverflow.com/users/1774643/ggrec
 *
 */
public class CustomMessageBox extends Dialog
{

    // ==================== 1. Static Fields ========================

    /*
     * Default ratio values for big dialogs
     */
    private static final double DEFAULT_DIALOG_WIDTH_SCREEN_PERCENTAGE = 0.63;
    private static final double DEFAULT_DIALOG_HEIGHT_SCREEN_PERCENTAGE = 0.75; 


    // ==================== Static Helper Methods ====================

    /**
     * <pre>
     * Very useful for dialogs. Resizes the dialog shell to a size proportional
     * to the primary monitor bounds.
     * 
     * <b>1920x1080 monitor && 0.63x0.75 ratios => 1400x800 shell</b>
     * 
     * This means 63% of screen's width, and 75% of screen's height.
     *
     * The advantage of this method is that the dialog will always be proportional
     * to the screen, no matter what the screen size is (e.g. big LG flat TV screen,
     * or MacOS display).
     * </pre> 
     *  
     * @param shell Dialog shell (e.g. the 'newShell' object in configureShell API from Dialog)
     * @param widthRatio A percentage of current screen's size (i.e. smaller than 1, bigger than 0)
     * @param heightRatio 
     */
    public static void resizeAndCenterShellOnScreen(final Shell shell, final double widthRatio, final double heightRatio)
    {
        final Display display = shell.getDisplay();
        final Monitor primaryMonitor = display.getPrimaryMonitor();
        final Rectangle monitorRect = primaryMonitor.getBounds();

        // 1.) Resize the Shell
        final int newWidth  = (int) Math.floor(monitorRect.width  * widthRatio);
        final int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(monitorRect.height * heightRatio);

        shell.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
        centerShellOnScreen(shell);
    }


    public static void centerShellOnScreen(final Shell shell)
    {
        final Rectangle shellBounds = shell.getBounds();

        final Display display = shell.getDisplay();
        final Monitor primaryMonitor = display.getPrimaryMonitor();
        final Rectangle monitorRect = primaryMonitor.getBounds();

        final int x = monitorRect.x + (monitorRect.width  - shellBounds.width)  / 2;
        final int y = monitorRect.y + (monitorRect.height - shellBounds.height) / 2;

        shell.setLocation(x, y);
    }


    // ==================== 3. Static Methods ====================

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new CustomMessageBox().open();
    }


    // ==================== 4. Constructors ====================

    public CustomMessageBox()
    {
        super(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell());
    }


    // ==================== 5. Creators ====================

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent)
    {
        final Composite dialogArea = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        final Label label = new Label(dialogArea, SWT.NULL);
        label.setText("YOLO");
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

        return dialogArea;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configureShell(final Shell newShell)
    {
        super.configureShell(newShell);

        resizeAndCenterShellOnScreen(newShell, DEFAULT_DIALOG_WIDTH_SCREEN_PERCENTAGE, DEFAULT_DIALOG_HEIGHT_SCREEN_PERCENTAGE);
    }

}
```

Cheers.